# Spark - Writing large dataframe problems

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hdfs

In Spark 2.2 (via YARN), I am trying to write a pretty large dataframe to HDFS via an overnight batch job. We first have two source tables, which we join, and then we write the joined result. The output is compressed parquet, but the write is failing due to an out of memory error.

We're providing 12 executors each with 20g of memory and 4 cores, plus the driver with 32g.

In a write operation like this, what runs out of memory? The executors? Short of blindly throwing more memory at it, what steps can we take to resolve this?

The join code is simple:

```
joined.write.option("header", "true").parquet(destPath)
```

Here are the final logs before a bunch of "heap dump" spam:

```
18/06/15 14:25:27 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_1385_piece0 in memory on company02.host.comp.com:43201 (size: 36.8 KB, free: 10.5 GB)
18/06/15 14:25:38 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 5982.0 in stage 1008.0 (TID 41953) in 63870 ms on company02.host.comp.com (executor 7) (5979/12136)
18/06/15 14:25:39 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 5984.0 in stage 1008.0 (TID 41955) in 65189 ms on company02.host.comp.com (executor 7) (5980/12136)
JVMDUMP039I Processing dump event "systhrow", detail "java/lang/OutOfMemoryError" at 2018/06/15 14:25:48 - please wait.
```

Comment: `joined` suggests there is a `join`, and `joins` are very expensive and prone to failures. Write alone, seldom causes problems.

Comment: does `joined` have enough partitions? You could change that e.g. by increasing `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions`. Also make sure your join-contitions is correct and you  don't have any "duplicates" in your source table (which would lead to multiplied records)

Comment: @RaphaelRoth Both of the tables that get joined are de-duped just prior. Does partitioning decrease memory usage? Is the shuffle partition setting you listed the same as calling .partition(##) on the dataframe via the code?

Comment: Three things that you could check: 1.) run a `joined.count` before writing. Does it run and does it produce the expected number of rows? 2.) run a `joined.explain(true)`. Do you see any unexpected operations or broadcasts that might be too large? 3.) do you see any exceptions or error messages on the executors?

Comment: @werner Given that part of the operation loads a huge amount of tiny parquet files, the explain is very large. Plus, I'm not quite sure what to look for. What would be some red flags?

Comment: @CubemonkeyNYC I'd look for unexpected joins (aka bugs in the code), especially ones that might create multiplied records. Another thing to check would be broadcasts that become too big (you could also try to set `spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold` to -1 to disable broadcasts at all). If the problem still persists, I'd try to cut off smaller parts of the dag to check if they run separately to narrow down the problem.

Comment: Here's the weirdest part that we just discovered. Leaving executor memory at default (1g) makes the job work reliably. Less memory, no out of memory errors. Any ideas on that one? I confirmed that we don't have any unexpected joins. The DAG looks normal, just huge because one layer reads in thousands of files. Read all -> join two df -> drop dupes -> write.